# Jetty, XML deployment: how to overcome folder access restriction

Tags: xml, deployment, permissions, jetty, war

I'm running Jetty 9 OK as http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-windows-service.html.

My Jetty deployable descriptor XML at `C:\opt\myappbase\webapps\deployable.xml` can't access my Windows user folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC 
    "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="war">C:/Users/Me</Set>
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
</Configure>
```

Upon launching `127.0.0.1:8080` in the browser I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource$1
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.addPath(FileResource.java:207)
...
```

When I change `C:\Users\Me` to `C:\Users\Public` it finds the directory OK.

How do I grant Jetty access to my ordinary Windows user folder?

Comment: Not really a developer / programmer question.  Seems like a serverfault (or poweruser) question.

Comment: I'm looking for a programmatic solution only. I don't want to manually change permissions on folders or anything like that.